# I need to replace spaces in a link with: %20

Tags: php

It's a membership site and the problem link is the one on the members profile page which is used to contact them. It works fine if the member is single but if they are a couple and their first name is 'John and Susan' the link doesn't work.

The code which displays the contact link is below. How can I change it so that, if there are any spaces in the first name part, it changes them to %20?

```
 <?php
 agent_with_listing ('  
 {lang_listed_by}: {listing_agent_first_name} - {check_agent} <a rel="colorbox" href="{contact_agent_link_url}">Click here to contact {listing_agent_first_name}{/check_agent}</a> '); 
  ?>
```

Comment: What templating engine are you using? There is probably a way to do it built in.

Comment: I guess this is smarty framework

Answer (score 2):

use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

It will convert space to `%20`

Answer (score 1):

It is not just spaces that you need to change.  Remeber this: you can NEVER put raw text in a link.  Instead use urlencode:

```
<?php
agent_with_listing ('  
    {lang_listed_by}: {listing_agent_first_name} - {check_agent} 
    <a rel="colorbox" href="'.urlencode($contact_agent_link_url).'">
        Click here to contact {listing_agent_first_name}{/check_agent}</a> '); 
?>
```

EXCEPT you should not urlencode an entire URL.  Instead, you should encode the data parts as you compose the url.  Something like:

```
$contact_agent_link_url = "http://myserver/app/".urlencode($first_name);
```

or

```
$contact_agent_link_url = "http://myserver/app/?foo=".urlencode($first_name);
```

Once the URL is composed with data correctly, it can be used as a link without danger.